# If $P \neq NP$ why doesn't this prove the existence of OWF?

Tags: one-way-function

i know that $P = NP \Rightarrow$ non existence of OWF.
but i don't understand why the claim:  $P \neq NP \Rightarrow$ existence of OWF is wrong?

An intuitive answer would be enough.

Comment: Where did you read that the claim is wrong?

Comment: the existence of a proof that P and NP are not equal would not directly imply the existence of one-way functions. wikipedia

Comment: i would guess that : it's not sufficient  for OWF to show that you can't solve for one input , but for np complete problem , its sufficient for just one input, but i want to make sure.

Comment: The wikipedia article links to [Goldwasser and Bellare's lecture notes](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gb.pdf).

Comment: I know I'm very late to the party, but aren't you asking why A => B <=/=> ~A => ~B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an answer from  Goldwasser and Bellare's lecture notes. 
P ≠ NP is not a sufficient one. P ≠ NP only implies that the encryption scheme is hard to break in the worst case. It does not rule-out the possibility that the encryption scheme is easy to break in almost all cases. In fact, one can easily construct “encryption schemes” for which the breaking problem is NP-complete and yet there exist an efficient breaking algorithm that succeeds on 99% of the cases. Hence, worst-case hardness is a poor measure of security. Security requires hardness on most cases or at least average-case hardness. Hence, a necessary condition for the existence of secure encryption schemes is the existence of languages in NP which are hard on the average. Furthermore, P≠ NP is not known to imply the existence of languages in NP which are hard on the average.

Comment: In addition, even a hard-on-average language in NP does not necessarily imply the existence of an "easy-to-compute and hard-to-invert" function.